# Vue creates Component before calculating data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm facing a issue with vue.
I have created a chart and i can initalize it with data, but when i press one of the check-boxes nothing happens, it happens one step later.

so for example:
I press check-box one: Nothing changes.
I press check-box two: Data of check-box one gets added
I press check-box one: Data of one and two are added
...

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks :)

App.vue

```
<template>
   <div v-if="show"> 
      <div id="Chart">
          <Chart v-bind:chartData="this.chartData"/>                         
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>        
      <checkbox @click="changeGraph">Select Data 1</checkbox>
      <checkbox @click="changeGraph">Select Data 2</checkbox>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
   name: 'App', 
   components: {
       Chart,
   },
   data () {
      return {
         chartData: {};
      }
   },
   methods: {
      changeGraph() {
        // Filling chartData in here
      }
   },
   mounted: {
      // init chartData here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `@click`, use `@change`

```
@click="changeGraph"
```

Comment: So i dont tried change before i did this post and it didn't work and now it does, i dont understand coding :D But still thank you very much :)

Comment: @Justin Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the object is not reactive to a property that it did not have a priori. For this you can use the `set` functionality of Vue:

```js
this.$set(object, property, value)

// or

import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.set(object, property, value)
```

This way the reactivity for that property will work.

You can read more about this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Comment: Will test if that also works, sounds like a safer solution :D